# How do I store intermediate data and share it between SQL queries? 

Tags: sql

Let's say I have four table (A,B,C,D), `empId` is common in all.

After running some complex query I get list of eligible `empIds`.

Now I need to run `Select .... from ..... where empId IN LIST`.

I want to store this list of `empIds` in some variable so that I don't have run complex query every time to get list of `empIds`.

Is there anyway to store `empIds` in some temporary space?

This way I can cut down in running this complex query every time.

Comment: What database system are you using? The syntax for using temporary tables differs between database brands.

Comment: How many `empIds` does the list contain?  How often do you want to query the list?  how long do you want to retain the list for?  Is the list common to users or constrained to a specific user?  How often does the data in the underlying tables change?  What do you want to do when the stored list becomes stale?   Have you done any benchmarking to confirm that the energy spent managing the cache will save you more than you would pend executing the original query on demand?

Comment: Thanks for the feed back guys, will take care next time.

Comment: I am usng oracle 11, empId my contain data in thousands and query will be used very frequently. Data in table too will change very frequent. I need to cache data in scope of stored procedure only, don't want to keep it for ever. And empId list will is out come of complex query can very. Everytime it can be on different query constarints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a table in memory using the syntax:

```
Select field1,field2,...fieldN INTO #tmp FROM SourceTable
```

Now you can access the contents of the table #tmp.

Comment: This is only valid if he runs all subsequent queries in the same session.

Comment: Is this syntax valid for Oracle 11i ??

Answer (score 1):

Since databases are optimized for joins you should store the expensive-to-get `empIds` in a table or view, and then join to that.

1. create table
2. insert ids to that table
3. join to temp table for free (or for cheap)

Since MySQL is allegedly "The world's most popular open source database" here is the syntax from their documentation:

**Step 1**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    (create_definition,...)
    [table_options]
    [partition_options]
```

Example for didactic use only:

```
CREATE TABLE expensive_ids (id);
```

**Step 2**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    SELECT ...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_name=expr, ... ]
```

Example for didactic use only:

```
INSERT INTO expensive_ids (id) VALUES (1);
```

**Step 3**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

```
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
```

Example for didactic use only:

```
SELECT my_other_table.id, expensive_ids.id
  FROM my_other_table 
       LEFT JOIN expensive_ids 
       ON expensive_ids.id = my_other_table.id;
```

Comment: I am usng oracle 11, empId my contain data in thousands and query will be used very frequently. Data in table too will change very frequent. I need to cache data in scope of stored procedure only, don't want to keep it for ever. And empId list will is out come of complex query can very. Everytime it can be on different query constarints